# Best way to install server-based .NET application shortcuts on client machines?

Tags: .net, networking, installation, inno-setup

I am working on a network version of a .NET WinForms application that only requires a shortcut to the EXE on the server to be present on the client's desktop. The users are non-technical / lay people so automating the shortcut creation is desirable. Click-Once is not an option. We are using Inno Setup.

Your suggestions/strategies are appreciated.

Comment: A little setup.exe that takes a command line argument for the path to the application is one way. EMail it. download it from your intranet.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks Tony but this application is to be distributed to a wide audience and we do not have the luxury of knowing what server path it will be installed on.

Comment: So you need installer on client side to get the path to the server application, but you don't know this path in advance, am I right ? Do you have another fixed path known in advance or maybe URL that could be used to get the server's application path ?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I am wondering how companies with thousands of clients automate this kind of operations. Is there a server side  method of doing this? I suppose the client setup could search every network path for the .EXE, but this seems problematic from a permissions standpoint.

Comment: I can't speak from large company view, but I would definitely prefer to use some sort of centralized system, not the search of a network. A simple web application returning the server app. path might be the one of the easiest solutions. It's pretty easy to [`invoke a web service`](http://turngeek.blogspot.cz/2012/04/making-web-request-within-inno-setup.html) from inside the InnoSetup.

Comment: After thinking about it, I totally agree. Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: Why the downvote ? In my view it's a good question. A downvoter could at least leave a comment why...

Comment: @rontornambe. Which ever way you deploy the shortcut, given that it's not a server something has to know where the short cut is going to point to. web service, config file in a well known location, a dynamic script. Not luxury, necessity.

Comment: I agree Tony. Since I am creating a shared folder in the setup program, perhaps adding a shortcut within this folder would provide a simple enough UI since it (shortcut) can be found in Network Places?

Answer (score 1):

I would personally prefer to use some sort of centralized system, never the search of a network. A simple web application returning the server app. path might be the one of the easiest solutions. Then it's pretty easy to [`invoke the web service`](http://turngeek.blogspot.cz/2012/04/making-web-request-within-inno-setup.html) from inside the InnoSetup.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the users know how to get to *somewhere* on the network, you can put the client installer there.  This can then use `{src}` to either locate the client executable (or an ini file that tells you where to find the client executable) in a run-direct-from-network scenario, or a config file you can install with the client executable in an install-locally-but-connect-to-server scenario.

Note that before choosing one of these strategies you should consider how often and what sort of process you want to follow to upgrade.  Any client running an app directly from a network share will typically hold the file locked so that you cannot replace it with an upgraded version, so you'd have to coordinate all your clients to shut down the app before upgrading.  Conversely, if files are installed locally then you'd need to coordinate all your clients to install the update when it is available.  (Both of these can be handled automatically in-application, of course -- but that's why it's important to consider this before deployment!)

Another option on a domain-based network is to simply force the app install on all clients via Active Directory deployment.

Comment: I'm afraid *the users know how to get to somewhere on the network* won't be this case, since *the users are non-technical / lay people* :-)

Comment: Maybe, but that's for the OP to decide.  But it's not hard for even non-technical people to get to places on the network, if they're used to doing that to get at other files -- it's pretty common, in fact.